# Opening a chat room to create a place where to discuss low quality answers

Tags: discussion

Just to inform you I have opened this chat room:

[image]

Link: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/68811/low-quality-answers

I believe it could be used to discuss with users, and give possibilities that are missing when just providing [a link to the help center](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Good plan, be aware that *very* low rep users will not be able to use chat. (Not the case in the one you've chosen to start with!)

Comment: @Jamiec They _could_ be invited by a moderator giving said user write access to the room.

Answer (score 8):

This is a commendable effort. Good luck getting users who write low-quality answers to engage with this effort and improve their answers. Even if only one joins in, that's still a benefit.

To all users: don't forget that the main chat room, [The Hangar](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/12036/the-hangar), also welcomes discussion about improving answers, whether they're low-quality or already almost perfect. It's also a great place to check before posting when you're not sure if your question is on-topic, or if your answer is appropriate.

Comment: Yeah, I think the new room is intended to slowly free The Hangar from long and frequent discussions of low-quality answers that may interrupt other discussions and also provide a way to let low-quality answers not just die.

Comment: @ΈρικΚωνσταντόπουλος: Yes, that's the point, focusing on this topic, allowing easier reuse of history, and avoiding automatic inclusion of all Hangar's user, giving some "privacy" to the discussion.

Comment: @mins Privacy? No (not a private room), but I don't see why it should be needed, since the subject is about stuff you publicly post.

Comment: @ΈρικΚωνσταντόπουλος: "Some privacy" in the sense users are usually in the Hangar, and rarely in the other rooms. I assume people prefer to discuss problems without having to answer multiple conversations.